# Install SMTP Service on Windows 2003 SP2 without Installation CD?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, smtp, installation

I need to modify my development environment, a virtual image using Windows 2003 SP2, to install the SMTP service under IIS (6.0).  The virtual image is a corporate build, and I do not have access to the installation disc (and going through the corporate channels, this may take several days).  Is there any way I can add the SMTP service without the install disc?

If there is alternative way of having an email service working on the virtual image, that also would be useful.

Thanks, MagicAndi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Agreed with Sam, if you don't have the disk or i386 folder, then you'll probably have difficulties.

You could try downloading Sp2, and extracting the i386 folder from it (it's a while ago when I tried that, and can't remember if it worked).

Alternatively, schmooze the IT dept, or go for some third party SMTP server.

I'd imagine the IT dept would rather you use the MS one, than install a third party app...

Cheers

Nick

Comment: This should actually work - You're specifically looking for the IIS6.cab file, I believe.

Comment: Old Nick, (not the Old Nick I sold my soul to when I started to work for a corporation?), Thanks, looks like a winner.  Accepted as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well the SMTP service installer needs some files from the installation disk, so if you don't have the disk, or you don't have the i386 folder on the machine somewhere, then you are a little stuck.

You could try and find the DLL's it asks for from the internet, but thats a pretty risky tactic, as they may not be what they claim to be and could cause you substantial problems.

Your other option is to install an alternative mail server on your machine, there are many free options available for Windows - [Mailenable](http://www.mailenable.com/standard_edition.asp), [Smartermail](http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterMail/Free-Windows-Mail-Server.aspx) etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could download an eval copy from MS and use that as your install source.

I *have* had some good luck with and extracted SP2 i386 folder in the past though, and - if memory serves - it worked fine one time with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the easiest way to do it is to pay a visit to your sysadmin team, and bring along cookies. Or beer, beer is good too.

Comment: ...or brownies...

Answer (score 0):

you can download SP2 for windows 2003 server - and use i386 folder :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to successfully install SNMP, for Windows 2003 Server, which requires the "second CD" or "i386" folder to complete the installation. Rather than finding and transferring that large amount or finding a way to mount it from a remote location. I've now just packed up my own SNMP requirements folder for when installing SNMP for Windows 2003. The required files, found in the i386 folder, include:

```
accserv.mib
apver.vbs
authserv.mib
dhcp.mib
evntagnt.dll
evntcmd.exe
evntwin.exe
ftpctrs.h2
ftpctrs.ini
ftp.mib
ftpmib.dll
hostmib.dll
hostmib.mib
http.mib
iis6.cab
inetsrv.mib
ipforwd.mib
lmmib2.dll
lmmib2.mib
mcastmib.mib
mib_ii.mib
mipx.mib
mripsap.mib
msft.mib
msipbtp.mib
msiprip2.mib
nipx.mib
rfc2571.mib
smierrsm.dll
smierrsy.dll
smi.mib
snmp.exe
snmpmib.dll
snmpreg.mof
snmpsmir.dll
snmpsmir.mof
snmpstup.dll
snmptrap.exe
snmp.zip
wfospf.mib
wins.mib
```

The only one I was not able to find was apver.vbs. I had to track that down online. I zipped it up and shared it to myself for easy access/deployment when needed. It's roughly 500KB compared to the 600MB I would need if finagling the "required" CD.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140603172311/http://www.netexpertise.eu/en/windows/snmp-files.html)