# Cannot install SMTP Service - Insert disk labeled "Service Pack 2 CD-ROM"

Tags: windows-server-2003, smtp, 64-bit, windows-server-2003-r2

We are running Windows Server 2003 R2 x64.  I am trying to install the smtp service.  I tried the solution posted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/76645/install-smtp-service-on-windows-2003-sp2-without-installation-cd), but When I pulled the files over, only the first missing dll was found.  Others, like wsmtpctrs.dll still could not be found (and others after that).

I downloaded the SP2 exe from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=08FEC2F5-6E3B-4E0D-9314-646414D0A421&displaylang=en#AffinityDownloads).

Then, I kicked off the installer on my local box (knowing it would fail).  I saved off the amd64 folder, and moved it up to the server.   I tried the same on the server, but the missing dll's still didn't appear.

Unfortunately, it STILL doesn't have all the files I need.  This is rather frustrating.

Comment: This is a development server.  Can I turn my windows 7 ultimate machine into a mail relay and have SSRS use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R2 != SP2  (just to be clear)

SP2 distribution file doesn't have ALL the files. You'll need the original OS install media to copy the AMD64 folder.    Then you'll need to "slipstream" the SP files into the baseline folder.

Next, in RegEdit, change all instances of "SourcePath" which point to windows installation files to point to the new, correct drive letter with the slipstreamed files.  Reboot to take effect.